# How to properly design USER table

Tags: database, hibernate

I've started designing a database and because I'm a beginner at it, I would like to ask what is the best way of designing in my case.

I have a database which should store details about web application users. However, the users are divided into two ( maybe three in the future ) groups, lets say "Customer" and "Worker". Both groups have common information ( email, login, password, etc. ) and some unique for the group.
In that case I wonder which solution is better: creating separate tables "CUSTOMER" and "WORKER" with duplicated columns ( "LOGIN", "PASSWORD" ) or to mark off the common information into one table "USER" and store "USER_ID" in the columns of "CUSTOMER" and "WORKER".

In the second case, how should it be resolved using hibernate 3.x annotations? Because it is not strictly OneToOne mapping.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html should provide a good starting point.

Comment: One approach is to have three tables. One for ALL users, one with your user groups, and the last table that has the relation between the users and groups id's. (Putting different users in different tables you will probably regret)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd prefer to have one table for users and a table for user roles ("Customer", "Worker" etc.) with many-to-many relationship.